# Extract only animation clips from a FBX model and delete everything else

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am trying to extract only the animation clips from a FBX model. At the moment, my script is able to rename animation clips. When I import a model to the assets folder, I can see the model and the animation clips when I expand it:

[image: Animation clip]

In the screenshot above, when I expand `Standing 2H Magic Attack 03`, there is the animation clip itself and an avatar. I want only the animation clip and nothing else. Here is my current script:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Reflection;
using UnityEditor;
using UnityEngine;

public class MixamoManager : EditorWindow
{
    private static MixamoManager editor;
    private static int width = 350;
    private static int height = 300;
    private static int x = 0;
    private static int y = 0;
    private static List<string> allFiles = new List<string>();

    [MenuItem("Window/Mixamo Manager")]
    static void ShowEditor()
    {
        editor = EditorWindow.GetWindow<MixamoManager>();
        CenterWindow();
    }

    private void OnGUI()
    {
        if (GUILayout.Button("Rename"))
        {
            Rename();
        }
    }

    public void Rename()
    {
        DirSearch();

        if (allFiles.Count > 0)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < allFiles.Count; i++)
            {
                int idx = allFiles[i].IndexOf("Assets");
                string filename = Path.GetFileName(allFiles[i]);
                string asset = allFiles[i].Substring(idx);
                AnimationClip orgClip = (AnimationClip)AssetDatabase.LoadAssetAtPath(
                     asset, typeof(AnimationClip));

                var fileName = Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(allFiles[i]);
                var importer = (ModelImporter)AssetImporter.GetAtPath(asset);

                RenameAndImport(importer, fileName);
            }
        }
    }

    private void RenameAndImport(ModelImporter asset, string name)
    {
        ModelImporter modelImporter = asset as ModelImporter;
        ModelImporterClipAnimation[] clipAnimations = modelImporter.defaultClipAnimations;

        for (int i = 0; i < clipAnimations.Length; i++)
        {
            clipAnimations[i].name = name;
        }

        modelImporter.clipAnimations = clipAnimations;
        modelImporter.SaveAndReimport();
    }

    private static void CenterWindow()
    {
        editor = EditorWindow.GetWindow<MixamoManager>();
        x = (Screen.currentResolution.width - width) / 2;
        y = (Screen.currentResolution.height - height) / 2;
        editor.position = new Rect(x, y, width, height);
        editor.maxSize = new Vector2(width, height);
        editor.minSize = editor.maxSize;
    }

    static void DirSearch()
    {
        string info = Application.dataPath; //+ "/Mixamo/Animations/medea_m_arrebola/Magic";
        string[] fileInfo = Directory.GetFiles(info, "*.fbx", SearchOption.AllDirectories);
        foreach (string file in fileInfo)
        {
            if (file.EndsWith(".fbx"))
                allFiles.Add(file);
        }
    }
}
```

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Does it have to be done through a script? I know that you can select an animation clip within an FBX file and hit `Ctrl+D` and it will generate a `.anim` file. Then you can delete the file entirely and leave just the animation.

Comment: U can try to automate what Razor said, try to create a copy of the animation and then delete the source file.